# Сортировка recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, recyclerview

Имеется recyclerview, который содержит список чатов. Я могу написать любому пользователю, но если до этого чат уже был создан, то он не поднимется выше (ну как в обычных мессенджерах).
Это код фрагмента с чатами:

```
class MessagesFragment : Fragment() {

    private var userAdapterSecond: UserAdapterSecond? = null
    private var mUsers: List<User>? = null
    private var usersChatList: List<ChatList>? = null
    lateinit var recycler_view_messages: RecyclerView
    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false)


        recycler_view_messages = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_messages)
        recycler_view_messages.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler_view_messages.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)


        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


        usersChatList = ArrayList()

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("ChatList").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
        ref!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                (usersChatList as ArrayList).clear()

                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val chatList = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatList::class.java)

                    (usersChatList as ArrayList).add(chatList!!)
                }
                retrieveChatList()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })


        return view
    }
}
```

Вот функция `retrieveChatList()`:

```
private fun retrieveChatList()
    {
        mUsers = ArrayList()

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
        ref!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                (mUsers as ArrayList).clear()

                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                    for (eachChatList in usersChatList!!)
                    {
                        if (user!!.getUID().equals(eachChatList.getId()))
                        {
                            (mUsers as ArrayList).add(user!!)
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (context != null)
                {
                    userAdapterSecond = UserAdapterSecond(context!!, (mUsers as ArrayList<User>), true)
                    recycler_view_messages.adapter = userAdapterSecond
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
```

В модуле `Chat` я получаю время. Вот код `UserAdapterSecond` для получения последнего сообщение и времени:

```
private fun retrieveLastMessage(chatUserId: String?, lastMessageTxt: TextView, timeMessage: TextView)
    {
        lastMsg = "defaultMsg"

        val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Chats")

        reference.addValueEventListener(object  : ValueEventListener{
            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val chat: Chat? = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat::class.java)

                    if (firebaseUser != null && chat != null)
                    {
                        if (chat.getReceiver() == firebaseUser!!.uid  &&
                            chat.getSender() == chatUserId  ||

                            chat.getReceiver() == chatUserId  &&
                            chat.getSender() == firebaseUser!!.uid)
                        {
                            lastMsg = chat.getMessage()!!
                            timeMessage.text = chat.getTime()
                        }
                    }

                }
                when(lastMsg)
                {
                    "defaultMsg" -> lastMessageTxt.text = "No Messages"
                    "Sent you an image" -> lastMessageTxt.text = "Photo"
                    else -> lastMessageTxt.text = lastMsg
                }
                lastMsg = "defaultMsg"
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)
            {

            }
        })
    }
```

А конкретно: `timeMessage.text = chat.getTime()`
Ну тут всё легко, никаких проблем нет. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На скрине показан сам фрагмент с чатами и временем. Можно заметить, что последний чат расположен не в самом верху, хотя написан он был сегодня (смотрите на дату и время).
Сам вопрос: как мне сортировать recyclerview так, чтобы сообщения с самой последней датой и временем были в самом начале списка? Код получения списка представлен выше.

Что получилось:

```
val chat: Chat? = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat::class.java)

(mUsers as ArrayList).add(user!!)
if (chat != null) {
    (mUsers as ArrayList).sortBy {chat.getTime()}
}
```

`UserAdapterSecond()`:

```
class UserAdapterSecond(private var mContext: Context,
                        private var mUser: List<User>,
                        isChatCheck: Boolean,
                        private var isFragment: Boolean = false) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{
    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
    private var isChatCheck: Boolean = isChatCheck

    var lastMsg: String = ""

    var x: String = ""
    var y: String = ""
    var z: String = ""
    var q: String = ""
    var w: String = ""
    var e: String = ""
    var r: String = ""
    var t: String = ""
    var m: String = ""
    var d: String = ""
    var o: String = ""
    var p: String = ""

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.messages_item_layout, parent, false)
        return UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mUser.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user = mUser[position]

        holder.userNameTextView.text = user.getUsername()
        holder.userFullnameTextView.text = user.getFullname()

        if (user.getDeleted() != "true")
        {
            Glide.with(mContext.applicationContext).load(user.getImage()).into(holder.userProfileImage)
        }
        else
        {
            Glide.with(mContext.applicationContext).load(R.drawable.profile_deleted_image).into(holder.userProfileImage)
        }


        if (isChatCheck)
        {
            retrieveLastMessage(user.getUID(), holder.lastMessageTxt, holder.timeMessage)
        }
        else
        {
            holder.lastMessageTxt.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.timeMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        }


        


        holder.linearUser.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(mContext, MessagesChatActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("userId", user.getUID())
            mContext.startActivity(intent)
        }


        holder.userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            pref.putString("profileId", user.getUID())
            pref.apply()

            (mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, OtherPeopleProfileFragment()).commit()
        })

        
    }

    class ViewHolder (@NonNull itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
        var userProfileImage: CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image_search)
        var userFullnameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_full_name_search)
        var userNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_search)
        var followButton: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.follow_btn_search)
        var followingButton: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.following_btn_search)
        var userMessages: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_messages)
        var linearUser: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_user)
        var lastMessageTxt: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_last)
        var onlineImageView: CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_online)
        var mp: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mp)
        var checkMark: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_mark)
        var heart: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.heart)
        var game: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.game)
        var timeMessage: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time)
    }


    private fun retrieveLastMessage(chatUserId: String?, lastMessageTxt: TextView, timeMessage: TextView)
    {
        lastMsg = "defaultMsg"

        val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Chats")

        reference.addValueEventListener(object  : ValueEventListener{

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
            @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val chat: Chat? = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat::class.java)

                    if (firebaseUser != null && chat != null)
                    {
                        if (chat.getReceiver() == firebaseUser!!.uid  &&
                            chat.getSender() == chatUserId  ||

                            chat.getReceiver() == chatUserId  &&
                            chat.getSender() == firebaseUser!!.uid)
                        {
                            lastMsg = chat.getMessage()!!

                            x = chat.getTime()!!

                            val now = LocalDateTime.now()
                            var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a dd-MM-yyyy")

                            q = formatter.format(now)

                            w = q.substringAfterLast(" ")
                            e = x.substringAfterLast(" ")

                            //год
                            r = w.substringAfterLast("-")
                            t = e.substringAfterLast("-")

                            //месяц
                            m = e.substringBeforeLast("-").substringAfterLast("-")

                            //день
                            d = e.substringBeforeLast("-").substringBeforeLast("-")

                            o = d[0].toString()

                            if (o == "0")
                            {
                                p = d.substringAfterLast("0")
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                p = d
                            }


                            z = " "

                            if (w == e)
                            {
                                y = x.substringBeforeLast(" ")
                            }

                            if (w != e && r==t)
                            {
                                if (m == "01")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Jan"
                                }
                                if (m == "02")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Feb"
                                }
                                if (m == "03")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Mar"
                                }
                                if (m == "04")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Apr"
                                }
                                if (m == "05")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "May"
                                }
                                if (m == "06")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Jun"
                                }
                                if (m == "07")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Jul"
                                }
                                if (m == "08")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Aug"
                                }
                                if (m == "09")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Sep"
                                }
                                if (m == "10")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Oct"
                                }
                                if (m == "11")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Nov"
                                }
                                if (m == "12")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Dec"
                                }
                            }

                            if (w != e && r!=t)
                            {
                                if (m == "01")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Jan" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "02")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Feb" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "03")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Mar" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "04")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Apr" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "05")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "May" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "06")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Jun" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "07")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Jul" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "08")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Aug" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "09")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Sep" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "10")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Oct" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "11")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Nov" + z + t
                                }
                                if (m == "12")
                                {
                                    y = p + z + "Dec" + z + t
                                }
                            }

                            timeMessage.text = y
                        }
                    }

                }
                when(lastMsg)
                {
                    "defaultMsg" -> lastMessageTxt.text = "No Messages"
                    "Sent you an image" -> {
                        lastMessageTxt.text = "Photo"
                        lastMessageTxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0080FF"))
                    }

                    else -> lastMessageTxt.text = lastMsg
                }
                lastMsg = "defaultMsg"
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)
            {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Передаю `getTime()` вместе с другими свойствами посланного сообщения. Функция работает, когда я нажимаю на кнопку отправить сообщение. В базу данных вносится само сообщения, id отправителя и получателя, время и так далее:

```
private fun sendMessageToUser(senderId: String, receiverId: String?, message: String)
    {
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
        val messageKey = reference.push().key

        val now = LocalDateTime.now()
        var formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a dd-MM-yyyy")

        val messageHashMap = HashMap<String, Any?>()
        messageHashMap["sender"] = senderId
        messageHashMap["message"] = message
        messageHashMap["receiver"] = receiverId
        messageHashMap["isseen"] = false
        messageHashMap["url"] = ""
        messageHashMap["messageId"] = messageKey
        messageHashMap["time"] = formatter.format(now).toString()
        reference.child("Chats")
            .child(messageKey!!)
            .setValue(messageHashMap)
            .addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                if (task.isSuccessful)
                {
                    val chatsListReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                        .reference
                        .child("ChatList")
                        .child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
                        .child(userId)

                    chatsListReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(object : ValueEventListener{
                        override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
                        {
                            if (!p0.exists())
                            {
                                chatsListReference.child("id").setValue(userId)
                            }

                            val chatsListReceiverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                                .reference
                                .child("ChatList")
                                .child(userId)
                                .child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
                            chatsListReceiverRef.child("id").setValue(firebaseUser!!.uid)
                        }

                        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError)
                        {

                        }
                    })


                    val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
                        .child("Users").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
                }
            }
    }
```

А вот модуль `Chat`:

```
class Chat
{
    private var sender: String = ""
    private var message: String = ""
    private var receiver: String = ""
    private var isseen = false
    private var url: String = ""
    private var messageId: String = ""
    private var time: String = ""

    constructor()

    constructor(
        sender: String,
        message: String,
        receiver: String,
        isseen: Boolean,
        url: String,
        messageId: String,
        time: String
    ) {
        this.sender = sender
        this.message = message
        this.receiver = receiver
        this.isseen = isseen
        this.url = url
        this.messageId = messageId
        this.time = time
    }


    fun getSender(): String? {
        return sender
    }

    fun setSender(sender: String?) {
        this.sender = sender!!
    }

    fun getMessage(): String? {
        return message
    }

    fun setMessage(message: String?) {
        this.message = message!!
    }

    fun getReceiver(): String? {
        return receiver
    }

    fun setReceiver(receiver: String?) {
        this.receiver = receiver!!
    }

    fun isIsSeen(): Boolean {
        return isseen
    }

    fun setIsSeen(isseen: Boolean?) {
        this.isseen = isseen!!
    }

    fun getUrl(): String? {
        return url
    }

    fun setUrl(url: String?) {
        this.url = url!!
    }

    fun getMessageId(): String? {
        return messageId
    }

    fun setMessageId(messageId: String?) {
        this.messageId = messageId!!
    }

    fun getTime(): String? {
        return time
    }

    fun setTime(time: String?) {
        this.time = time!!
    }
}
```

Comment: Ну Вы каждый раз задаете новый адаптер для RecyclerView, что не есть хорошо.... А на счет сортровки данных, так перед тем как ложить массив сообщений в адаптер и вызывать у него notifyDatasetChanged() необходимо этот самый массив сообщений отсортировать примерно так: items.sortedBy{it.lastTime} или в обратном порядке: items.sortedByDescending{it.lastTime}

Comment: @beeline09 я понимаю, что я каждый раз задаю новый адаптер, но не понимаю, где, и как это исправить

Comment: вот здесь: `if (context != null)
                {
                    userAdapterSecond = UserAdapterSecond(context!!, (mUsers as ArrayList<User>), true)
                    recycler_view_messages.adapter = userAdapterSecond
                }`

Вы каждый раз задаете новый адаптер. А надо его где-нибудь выше инициализировать и один раз привязать к RecyclerView.

Comment: Пришлите код Вашего адаптера и я помогу

Comment: @beeline09 показал код в правках, спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Контекст передавать в адаптер плохо. Утечки памяти и прочее

`retrieveLastMessage()` - очень не хорошо получать данные в адаптере! Вообще вешать какую-либо логику на адаптер - плохо. Каждый класс должен делать что-то одно. Адаптер должен быть максимально тупой и служить только отображения данных в списке.

`isChatCheck` - просто вызываем `adapter.isChatCheck = true/false` и тогда все перерисуется с учетом isChatCheck. Не надо его передавать в адаптере каждый раз

`(mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, OtherPeopleProfileFragment()).commit()` - это устаревшее решение. Лучше всего использовать Jetpack Navigation.

Что происходит в `retrieveLastMessage()`? DateTimeFormatter требует последних версий Андроид. Все можно сделать проще с помощью `SimpleDateFormat`
Переделал все внутри `override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)`

В объявлении адаптера тоже ошибка. Там указано, что вьюхолдер он использует от `UserAdapter.ViewHolder`, а должен использовать свой: `UserAdapterSecond.ViewHolder`. Исправил.

Ну а теперь сам код))) Для начала создаем в проекте файл DateExtensions.kt и кладем в него следующее содержимое:

```html
import java.util.*

//Екстеншн. Проверяем дату на то в этом году она или нет
fun Date.isInCurrentYear(): Boolean {
    val currDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
    val srDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).apply { time = this@isInCurrentYear }
    return srDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) == currDate.get(Calendar.YEAR)
}

//Екстеншн. Проверяем дату на то сегодня она или нет
fun Date.isToday(): Boolean {
    val currDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault())
    val srDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault()).apply { time = this@isToday }
    return srDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) == currDate.get(Calendar.YEAR) && srDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) == currDate.get(
        Calendar.MONTH
    ) && srDate.get(
        Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH
    ) == currDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
}
```

Вот переделанный MessagesFragment:

```html
class MessagesFragment : Fragment() {

    private var userAdapterSecond: UserAdapterSecond = UserAdapterSecond( isFragment = true)
    private var mUsers: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()
    private var usersChatList: List<ChatList>? = null
    lateinit var recycler_view_messages: RecyclerView
    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = null

    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_messages, container, false)


        recycler_view_messages = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view_messages)
        recycler_view_messages.setHasFixedSize(true)
        recycler_view_messages.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)


        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


        usersChatList = ArrayList()

        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("ChatList").child(firebaseUser!!.uid)
        ref!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                (usersChatList as ArrayList).clear()

                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val chatList = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatList::class.java)

                    (usersChatList as ArrayList).add(chatList!!)
                }
                retrieveChatList()
            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })


        return view
    }

    private fun retrieveChatList()
    {


        val ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Users")
        ref!!.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot)
            {
                mUsers.clear()

                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children)
                {
                    val user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User::class.java)

                    for (eachChatList in usersChatList!!)
                    {
                        if (user!!.getUID().equals(eachChatList.getId()))
                        {
                            mUsers.add(user!!)
                        }
                    }
                }

                userAdapterSecond.isChatCheck = true
                userAdapterSecond.setData(mUsers)

            }

            override fun onCancelled(p0: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

Ну и сам адаптер:

```html
class UserAdapterSecond(
    private var isFragment: Boolean = false
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapterSecond.ViewHolder>() {

    private var mUser: MutableList<User> = mutableListOf()

    fun setData(items: List<User>) {
        mUser.clear()
        mUser.addAll(items)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    var isChatCheck: Boolean = true
        set(value) {
            field = value
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }


    private var firebaseUser: FirebaseUser? = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser


    var lastMsg: String = ""

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): UserAdapterSecond.ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.messages_item_layout, parent, false)
        return UserAdapterSecond.ViewHolder(view)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return mUser.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: UserAdapterSecond.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val user = mUser[position]

        val mContext = holder.timeMessage.context

        holder.userNameTextView.text = user.getUsername()
        holder.userFullnameTextView.text = user.getFullname()

        if (user.getDeleted() != "true") {
            Glide.with(mContext.applicationContext).load(user.getImage())
                .into(holder.userProfileImage)
        } else {
            Glide.with(mContext.applicationContext).load(R.drawable.profile_deleted_image)
                .into(holder.userProfileImage)
        }


        if (isChatCheck) {
            retrieveLastMessage(user.getUID(), holder.lastMessageTxt, holder.timeMessage)
        } else {
            holder.lastMessageTxt.visibility = View.GONE
            holder.timeMessage.visibility = View.GONE
        }





        holder.linearUser.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(mContext, MessagesChatActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("userId", user.getUID())
            mContext.startActivity(intent)
        }


        holder.userProfileImage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
            val pref = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            pref.putString("profileId", user.getUID())
            pref.apply()

            (mContext as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fragment_container, OtherPeopleProfileFragment()).commit()
        })


    }

    class ViewHolder(@NonNull itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var userProfileImage: CircleImageView =
            itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_profile_image_search)
        var userFullnameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_full_name_search)
        var userNameTextView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_name_search)
        var followButton: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.follow_btn_search)
        var followingButton: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.following_btn_search)
        var userMessages: ImageButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.user_messages)
        var linearUser: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linear_user)
        var lastMessageTxt: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_last)
        var onlineImageView: CircleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_online)
        var mp: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mp)
        var checkMark: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.check_mark)
        var heart: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.heart)
        var game: ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.game)
        var timeMessage: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.message_time)
    }


    private fun retrieveLastMessage(
        chatUserId: String?,
        lastMessageTxt: TextView,
        timeMessage: TextView
    ) {
        lastMsg = "defaultMsg"

        val firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        val reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference.child("Chats")

        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener {

            @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                for (dataSnapshot in p0.children) {
                    val chat: Chat? = dataSnapshot.getValue(Chat::class.java)

                    if (firebaseUser != null && chat != null) {
                        if (chat.getReceiver() == firebaseUser!!.uid &&
                            chat.getSender() == chatUserId ||

                            chat.getReceiver() == chatUserId &&
                            chat.getSender() == firebaseUser!!.uid
                        ) {
                            lastMsg = chat.getMessage()!!

                            val formatter =
                                SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())

                            if (chat.getTime()!!.isToday()) {
                                formatter.applyPattern("HH:mm")
                            } else if (!chat.getTime()!!.isToday() && chat.getTime()!!
                                    .isInCurrentYear()
                            ) {
                                formatter.applyPattern("d MMM")
                            } else {
                                formatter.applyPattern("d MMM yyyy")
                            }

                            timeMessage.text = formatter.format(chat.getTime()!!)
                        }
                    }

                }
                when (lastMsg) {
                    "defaultMsg" -> lastMessageTxt.text = "No Messages"
                    "Sent you an image" -> {
                        lastMessageTxt.text = "Photo"
                        lastMessageTxt.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0080FF"))
                    }

                    else -> lastMessageTxt.text = lastMsg
                }
                lastMsg = "defaultMsg"
            }

            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

            }
        })
    }
}
```

У меня, естественно, код не компилируется, проверить не могу, но думаю, что сразу должно заработать как надо.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Но адаптер не видит `isToday` и `isInCurrentYear`. Возможно, надо как-то передать эти значения из DateExtensions. Или в модуле `chat` добавить

Comment: Как так-то? Может просто надо импортировать все? Нажмите на isToday и нажмите Alt+Enter.
Или я начинаю понимать.... Этот экстеншн для типа Date. Какой тип Вам отдает chat.getTime()? Предполагаю, что типы не совпадают и его надо как-то преобразовать в Date, либо переписать экстеншн на тот тип, который возвращает chat.getTime().

Comment: ну да, `getTime()` у меня string

Comment: Я попытался преобразовать типы данных, но ничего хорошего из этого не получилось(

Comment: А, ну тогда все понятно. В каком формате приходит дата в строке? Вот в таком же формате надо дату распарсить с помощью SimpleDateFormatter

Comment: не помогает. Я пробовал привести данные к одному типу - не помогло. Я в правках показал код, в котором я передаю значение `getTime()`

Comment: ещё показал модуль `Chat`

Comment: val df = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault())
val date = df.parse(chat.getTime())
так мы получим нашу дату как Date

Comment: Я всё сделал, ошибки пропали, но вместе с ними и все сообщения. То есть теперь у меня пустой фрагмент, там нет ни одного последнего сообщения

Comment: Тут может быть очень много вариантов. Научитесь пользоваться отладкой, если еще не умеете. Так можно поймать нужные данные в нужном месте и понять почему не работает. Вероятнее всего, если ничего не отображается, вы забыли назначить адаптер RecyclerView

Comment: Если у Вас получилось, не забываем помечать ответ как правильный.

Answer (score 1):

Есть опасения относительно вашей структуры. Но в целом у вас не должно возникать проблем. Убедитесь, что вы не создаете адаптер каждый раз при изменении данных. Приведу пример:

```
class ClientAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<Client, ClientAdapter.Holder>() {

    private val _items = mutableListOf<Client?>()

    var items: List<Client?>
        get() = _items
        set(value) {
            _items.clear()
            _items.addAll(value)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }
}
```

Как видите при обновлении данных я не буду создавать новый адаптер, я просто сделаю: `adapter.items = listOf<Clients>` из своей активити. Вам просто нужно будет перед поставлением данных сортировать этот список `items.sortBy { it.time }`

Comment: Если честно, это не очень помогает. Я показал свой код в правках. Ничего не изменилось

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, привести пример, используя мой код? А то я что-то совсем не понимаю

Comment: @vlad-orlinskas привел правильный пример. Пришлите свой код адаптера и мы поможем это все оформить во фрагменте.